# Purpose of -1 in String.fromCharCode(k)

Tags: javascript, fromcharcode

I have the following snippet of code :

```
return (AllowableCharacters.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(k)) != -1);
```

Now, I don't quite get the usage of -1 in this script.

The way the script reads is as follows:

`first String.fromCharCode(k) != -1` is executed (k is a key code , I am dynamically getting from some other script).

Then I get the indexof(String.fromCharCode(k) != -1) from AllowableCharacters.

Which is a string something like this:

```
AllowableCharacters = "abc" ;
```

I also understand that if the indexof can't find a value in the above string it return -1.

Coming back to my question, however, why the -1 in the script?

**EDIT ::**

To make my question simpler , how would you read the following line :

```
String.fromCharCode(k))!=-1
```

**in simple plain english .**

**EDIT 2::**

ok so i just read guffa's answer and made a random script to check , heres the script :

```
 var store = "abcdefgpS";

        function check_index(){
            console.log(store.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(83))); 
        };
```

in the above function the !-1 is excluded , so on console.log , if a match is found we get the indexOf where the character was found and well if a match is not found we get -1 .

**NOW ,** now thats not what we want , what we want is a "tell me if the value is there"(return true) or "tell me if the value is not there"(return false).

so what we do is we change the above script to :

```
 var store = "abcdefgpS";

        function check_index(){
            console.log(store.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(83)) !-1); 
        };
```

which, gives ur true or false values .

now how does :

return (store.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(83)) !-1)

read as :

```
if (store.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(83)) !-1){
      return true;
}else { return false; }
```

**I don't see the if statement in . 
`return (store.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(83)) !-1);`**

Thank you,

Alexander

Comment: simple answer is can't check for truthy because `0` is a valid index but isn't truthy. Thus indexing methods use `-1` to represent it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the order of execution wrong.

First this expression is evaluated: `String.fromCharCode(k)`.

Lets assume that the result is the string `"b"`. That is used in the expression: `AllowableCharacters.indexOf("b")`.

Lets assume that the characer is found at the second character in the string, which has index 1, so the result is `1`. That is used in the expression `1 != -1`.

As the `1` is not equal to `-1`, the result is `true`, which is returned.

In short, the `-1` is compared with the result from the `indexOf` method, as the methods returns `-1` when it doesn't find anything.

---

It's the comparison operator `!=` that causes the value to be `true` or `false`. It compares the values, and the result depends on whether they are equal or not. An `if` statement isn't needed to turn the result into `true` or `false`, that's already the value of the comparison expression.

Sometimes you see code like:

```
if (AllowableCharacters.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(k)) != -1) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

The `if` statement is superflous in cases like that. The expression in the `if` statement is already `true` or `false`, so it can be returned directly:

```
return AllowableCharacters.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(k)) != -1;
```

Comment: +1 for ur answer , but can you checkout my edit2 Please and try editing your answer to that question of mine too , as thats the part thats confusing me .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: I added some further explanation, hope it clears some things up.

Answer (score 2):

This is a condition that validates whether or not a character is allowed. It will return a `boolean` (the result of the comparison).

Let's break it down.

1. First, we get a string from a char code with `String.fromCharCode`. Presumably we've received this from an input event of some kind.
2. Next, we get the index of this resulting single-character string in `AllowableCharacters` using `indexOf`.
3. Finally, we test if that result is `-1`. A test evaluates to a `boolean` value, and it can be returned from a function just like any other value. A value of `-1` indicates that the character is not allowed, so we use `!=` to determine if the character is valid.

Comment: is it some kind of an if statement ??

Comment: can you be a bit more elaborate , i have been struggling with this for like almost a day now. Thanks.

Comment: Thats , but can you check out my Edit2 and try answering that too , thats would be pretty much my last question.